# Strangely ordered text messages

Tags: messaging

I've only had my Nokia Lumia 630 for about a month and its always been fine. Suddenly whenever I send a text message, it appears halfway or at the top of the list. They're not even in order!! What do I do??

Answer (score 2):

The date and time show on sent messages is per your phone's clock, but the received, are per the network's time. If you find the messages show out of order, ensure that the time on you phone is as accurate as possible.